# Codesign only succeeds after other xcode iphone project is successfully signed

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

I have a weird issue. Codesign refuses to sign this big project I have, project A, but does signs the other, project B. However, when I have signed project B, it also can sign project A all of a sudden. I am 100% certain I didn't change anything else. The steps I took were:

Try to build, sign A - fails on signing
Try to build, sign B - succeeds
Try to build, sign A - succeeds

Transcript:

```
CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/CPPlayer.app
cd /Users/nick/CPPlayer
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Nick Overdijk (PM7C8QKTYS)" --resource-rules=/Users/nick/CPPlayer/build/Debug-iphoneos/CPPlayer.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/nick/CPPlayer/build/CPPlayer.build/Debug-iphoneos/CPPlayer.build/CPPlayer.xcent /Users/nick/CPPlayer/build/Debug-iphoneos/CPPlayer.app

/Users/nick/CPPlayer/build/Debug-iphoneos/CPPlayer.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

In pictures: [See here (imageshack gallery)](http://img265.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=screenshot20091211at101.png)

Is there anything I could've missed? Any ideas how this can happen? I got everything working now and this seems a cure for my problem, but I'd like to understand what is happening.

Sometimes it also works like this:
Build/sign A - succeeds
Build/sign A - fails
Build/sign B - succeeds (B always seems to succeed)
Build/sign A - succeeds
Build/sign A - fails

So, after every successful build of A, I have to build and sign B to be able to sign project A again. I can rebuild project B any number of times in succession, it always succeeds.

I'm not sure if it matters, but also when I try to run it in the simulator (debug mode for iPhone OS 3.1.2) it fails to install each other time. So:

Build/run - Fails
Build/run - Works
Build/run - Fails
Build/run - Works

This goes only for Project A, I can build and run project B as many times as I like, I never get the message that the installation failed.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: Check in the Overview popup to see if you have multiple devices configured for the first project.  If you do, it's possible that one device matches your provisioning profile/signing certificate, and the other doesn't, and that the second project is configured for the correct device and sets that to be your active device.

Also it would help to hover over the right edge of the Codesign step, disclose the transcript, and copy and paste it.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was such a button. The transcript is in the original post. There are no differences in the overview besides the project name, they are both being signed for one iPod with the same name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem could be too many info.plist files.

I had the same problem (alternating codesign success and failure).

I had added a directory of source code to my project, with "add existing files" on the directory.  Turns out there was a **info.plist** file in the directory, so I now had 2 of them in my project.  I deleted the new one and removed it from the project, and my problem was solved.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks a lot, this was indeed the case. I was planning on making targets, so included a Info.plist in the "target's directory" but then I didn't create targets so I indeed had an Info.plist and some other Info.plist (with some other name but I set xcode to use that file as Info.plist). Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: You are my hero as well! It worked for me. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: I don't know why I created another file like MyApp-Info.plist. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the specific error message

```
object file format invalid or unsuitable
```

I got these links:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/2009/04/json-framework-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable/

which suggest that your ResourceRules.plist is not set up correctly.  That solution seems to have helped a lot of folks with this problem.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't do the trick. Still the same problem. Works once, then I have to rebuild/sign the other project (B) again. Project B is a iPhone app that displays a tableview with 1 clickable cell, which, when clicked, changes the view to another one. A tutorial program really. Nothing fancy in there.

Comment: I don't know if it's interesting, but my I can also simulate the project only trying to build and run it twice. It fails each other time. More clearly explained in original post.

Answer (score 2):

I also was struggling with the 'Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1' error message.

Here is how I solved it

Right-click on **info.plist** look at it's targets. Make sure the box to the left is UNCHECKED. This is the default state.

Targeting the files don't work fine for the info.plist.

Comment: That was exactly the solution to the problem in XCode 4! Remove the plist under target->build phases->copy bundle ressources.

Comment: That was also my solution. I think the new Xcode 4.2 "clean settings" feature added one Info.plist to both my targets, had to undo this change.

Answer (score 1):

the issue happened to me, tried every combination of cert, provisioning profile, cleans and restarts, frustrating the damn system doesn't tell you what the issue is. just let me keep guessing. the solution for me was the above referenced article.

"Executable name" must match "Product Name"

really saved me to find this here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have more than one Info.plist file in your target!